# How to get fields from secondary list that are not identifed in the lookup into a single view?

Tags: sharepoint

I have 2 lists in SharePoint and one of them is a list of applications and another is tasks.  The task list has a lookup column pointed at the App List: Name column.  My App list contains some other information such as Department Name.

**TASK LIST**
- Work Number
- Resource
- Name
- Priority
- Application Name (*Lookup to Application List*)
- Completion Date

**TASK LIST**
- Application Name
- Department (*Lookup to Departments List*)
- Primary Dev

**New View**
- Task Name
- Task Status
- Task ETC
- Application Name
- Department Name
- Primary Dev

> I am basically trying to create a view
>   that includes some columns from the
>   Task List and all of the columns from
>   the Application list.  I know in SQL
>   this is simply a JOIN to get the other
>   fields, but I'm not sure how to do
>   this with SharePoint views.

Comment: Can you please rephrase the last line, it's a little unclear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sorry if this is way off (my head is too full of post-workweek buzz to fully grasp your problem statement), but is this what you are looking for?

http://blah.winsmarts.com/2007-10-Performing_joins_between_SharePoint_lists.aspx
http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepointdesigner/HA100991441033.aspx

Comment: Yeah, that is on the right track... Just don't want to do more here than what my users can do...

Comment: Then you are out of luck, because AFAIk SharePoint doesn't offer such functionality through the standard interface.

Comment: Doh!  Seems like such an obvious feature to include too.  Hey Microsoft, You listening?

Comment: Well, they might be. In SharePoint 2010 they do make "joins" a much more accessible part of a view when using the SharePoint Object Model... they might have done some tweaking to the interface as well, but I haven't looked at it yet.